# How to run a ruby on rails server on a microsoft azure ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, web-deployment

So I am a total newbie to Microsoft azure and deploying applications on a server, I've seen a bunch of tutorials for deploying a rails application on azure, but they all use the classic portal. I'm using the new portal with the resource manager, and I've got no idea how to translate what those tutorials want into the new resource manager deployment model.

So yeah I already have the virtual machine set up. I already have the rails app in it, and I can run it locally inside the server just fine using the `rails s` command, but how do I actually run it in a way that is accessible through the web, where I can type in the DNS I set up in azure and get to the rails server interface?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure doesn't control your DNS server and it's records. You just have to look up the Public IP of the VM (and you'd better [make it static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal), so it won't change) and create A record in your DNS to point to that IP.
As for the connectivity, you would want to look into the Network Security Groups, to [allow for incoming traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal).

Comment: But you can set up a DNS name label on Azure otherwise that's this about http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1866663/7ba0403fb35c87a145d2163e88c63263

Comment: if you do that, you would get a FQDN like this `DNS_LABEL.REGION.cloudapp.azure.com`

Comment: so when i do do the connectivity thing to route traffic to my rails server, and have this DNS set up, i should be able to access the rails server interface through it right ?

Comment: yes, you would create a Public IP and allow port 80 (or whatever is it you want) on the Network Security Group and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost, i allowed for incoming traffic and associated it with my VM following the link you sent me, and i started up my rails server on the command line through ssh, but how do i make it so the rails server interface accessible.  Because right now i can run the server just fine on the command line, but i can't as i do locally when i run a rails server and just go to localhost:3000 and see the interface, that's my end goal i want a url so i can send it to other people.

Comment: well, just like I said, if you created a DNS Label (say `MYAPP`) and your VM region is `northeurope`, your address would look like: `myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`, so the link would be `http://myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:3000`.

Comment: I tried accessing it through this url, but it just tried to load the page and there's just no response, just a blank screen that is constantly loading

Comment: well, can you verify you opened proper port? can you verify you opened that port on the VM itself (iptables or whatever) can you verify that the service is listening?

Comment: I am a total newbie : ( i don

Comment: well, judging from the previous conversation - i assume you need to open up the port on the VM itself. so there's a firewall on the VM that must be opened to allow for incoming connections to that port.